# How non entry point (random) process running inside Windows Container could write to docker default log output (stdout)?

Tags: logging, docker, container, stdout, docker-for-windows

So, I have one Windows Container with **various processes**, .NET and Win32 legacy applications.

### First scenario

Entry Point calls *myConfigurator.exe*, who calls *first.exe*, who creates a pool of *second.exe*

### Second scenario

Entry Point calls *myConfigurator.exe*, who calls *ServiceMonitor.exe*, who initialize my IIS ASP.NET Web Application, who creates a pool of *second.exe* process

## Problem

I'm already using log4net appender to send all logs to elasticsearch, and it's all good.

**But, I need to send logs to default docker log too**, so datacenter operators can see logs the same way they do with standard/compliant containers, using portainer or any other tool.

## Question

**How random processes running inside Windows Container could write to default log output?**

Knowing how it works, maybe I could write a custom *appender* or something.

Thanks!

JP